# handle 2 touch at the same time android

Tags: android, events, touch

How can i detect if a person clicked on the screen at the same time on 2 different places.
im using the normal way to get the action

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    doSomething();      

}
```

If i press on 2 different places on my screen the `doSomething();` is activated one time, but i want it to be activated 2 times since there is 2 clicks on screen, how can i achieve that ?

I tried with `event.getActionMasked()` but could not get it to work.

Comment: If you touch at same time on screen then only you can use MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN

Comment: How to use it ? i tried : if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
   doSomething();
  }
but it didnt work, now if i click on the screen at the same time it runs the doSomething once.

Comment: read it twice what i said: "If you touch at same time on screen then you can use MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN"

Comment: it doesn't mean that your method will be called twice

Comment: So there is no way to make that function to run twice if i receive 2 touch on the same time ?

Comment: yes there is no way if touch is at same time

Comment: Is there a way to get the x,y for each click or not ?

Answer (score 0):

If you touch with 2 fingers at same time then touchlistener will take it as single event and in this case it will call MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN